# assign public IPs to vm guests

Tags: centos, virtual-machines, kvm-virtualization, libvirt, bridge

I have a set of public IPs for virtual machines. Each unique public IP is to be assigned to a unique guest. With bridged networking I share eth0 with KVM machines.

The ifcfg-eth0 file has configuration:

```
DEVICE=eth0
ONBOOT=yes
BRIDGE=br0
HWADDR=b8:ac:6f:65:31:e5
DNS1=8.8.8.8
TYPE=Ethernet
```

The ifcfg-br0 file has configuration:

```
DEVICE=br0
TYPE=Bridge
BOOTPROTO=static
ONBOOT=yes
IPADDR=121.33.7.1
GATEWAY=121.33.7.0
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
DELAY=0
DNS1=8.8.8.8
```

I use the default libvirt network file, a bridge summary returns

```
bridge name   bridge id         STP enabled interfaces
br0           8000.705240103540 no          eth0
                                            virtual-machine-0
                                            virtual-machine-1
                                            virtual-machine-2
                                            virtual-machine-3
```

It works fine for guest with both incoming connections and outgoing connections. But the problem with the configuration is that if a guest changes his network file in vm with another availabe public ip, he would be able to obtain the ip that isn't originally assigned to his vm. How to assign a particular public ip to a guest network interface?

Comment: Switch port security? 802.1x? The fact that these are _virtual_ machines doesn't matter that much.

Comment: Assign the IPs from a DHCP server?  Don't configure the IPs in the guests at all?

Comment: No, a vm guest in my host must have a static public ip that never changes.

Answer (score 1):

Just found the right way to do it. Add a etables reule so that the vm guest that has interface virtual-machine-0 can use ip 121.33.7.5 only.

```
ebtables -A FORWARD -i virtual-machine-0 -p IPv4 --ip-src ! 121.33.7.5 -j DROP
```